# returned function result is confused in conditional statement

Tags: php

I have a class that works with database in PHP. the Add function in this class is:

```
    function Add($post_id)
    {
        if(!is_numeric($post_id))
        {
            return 1181;
        }

        $query  = "...";
        $result = mysql_query($query, $this->link);
        return $result;
    }
```

I also have a page that gets a form data and passes them to this class. The page code is:

```
$result = $obj->Add($post_id);

if($result == 1181)
{
    echo 'invalid';
}
else if($result)
{
    echo 'success';
}
else
{
    echo 'error';
}
```

the returned value is 1 and the output must be 'success', but i get 'invalid' message. If i swap 'invalid' and 'success' conditional statements, everything works well, but i want to know that what's this problem for?

Comment: And what's the input? How are we supposed to deduce the problem if we don't know what `$post_id` is?

Comment: It looks to me like you should be using exceptions, not returning numbers like "1181". What does that number _mean_?

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal: `$post_id` is a digit value. i didn't use from Exceptions because i wanna prevent sql injection and i also have some other codes after checking `$post_id`. everything is normal but i dont know that what is this problem...

Comment: i think that $result is returning you a "1181" if swap them of course it will "work" because $result will always be defined ... @Tomalak is right you should be using exception, debug what does result is once you call the Add method, and let us know!!

Comment: I don't see the correlation between Exceptions and SQL injection.

Comment: @Novice: Exceptions and SQL injection are completely orthogonal. "i didn't use from Exceptions because i wanna prevent sql injection" makes no sense. And tell us the **exact, specific value of `$post_id`** instead of giving us meaningless vague nonsense.

Comment: you are right. i changed my codes...but i'm confused. @Tomalak: `$post_id` is 147...

Comment: @Novice: Then the result cannot be `1181`, and the output cannot be `"invalid"`. You need to [give us a testcase](http://sscce.org/) because there is no way we can answer your question yet.

Answer (score 5):

`var_dump($result);` is a good starting point. in boolean context 1181 will be converted to `true`, so just because it prints `success` don't expect that it succeeded.

You probably pass the wrong `post_id`. Enable displaying warnings and notices. Don't use crazy magic constants, use `false` or throw an exception. Always check the return value of `mysql_query`.

If you do that I don't have to guess and you can make progress and ask meaningful questions.

Comment: +1: Quite right. This is the best answer possible for this question at present.

Comment: 1181 is true but i check it with equality operator. this condition is false because the returned value is 1. all right? im used from numbers because i have so error numbers in this method, like "invalid email". i can't show all of them with false value. of course i changed it to using Exceptions

Comment: @Novice: assert `var_dump( true == 1181 )`. This answer is correct. You should use the strict equality operator `var_dump( true === 1181 )` if you want the result that you expect.

Comment: let's be pragmatic: `var_dump($post_id);` `var_dump($result);`

Comment: thanks guys. 1)for the main problem as dear fireeyedboy says, i used from identical operator and it works well 2) i changed the main code to using Exceptions against returning numbers...

Answer (score 2):

Like others have pointed out in the comments, you should be using [Exceptions](http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php) in these types of cases. Here's an example.

```
function Add($post_id)
{
    if(!is_numeric($post_id))
    {
        throw new InvalidArgumentException( 'Argument should be numeric' );
    }

    $query  = "...";
    $result = mysql_query($query, $this->link); 
    return $result;
}

try
{
    $result = $obj->Add($post_id);
}
catch( InvalidArgumentException $e )
{
    /* handle the invalid argument exception */
}

if($result)
{
    echo 'success';
}
else
{
    echo 'error';
}
```

Furthermore, if you insist on using codes for your errors, you might use this:

```
function Add($post_id)
{
    if(!is_numeric($post_id))
    {
        throw new InvalidArgumentException( 'Argument should be numeric', 1181 );
    }

    if($post_id <= 0)
    {
        throw new InvalidArgumentException( 'Argument should be larger than 0', 1182 );
    }

    $query  = "...";
    $result = mysql_query($query, $this->link); 
    return $result;
}

try
{
    $result = $obj->Add($post_id);
}
catch( InvalidArgumentException $e )
{
    switch( $e->getCode() )
    {
        case 1181:
            /* handle the invalid argument exception with code 1181 */
            break;
        case 1182:
            /* handle the invalid argument exception with code 1182 */
            break;
        default:
            /* handle other invalid argument exceptions */
            break;
    }
}
```

Lastly, like others have commented also, exception handling has nothing to do with, and does not interfere with preventing SQL injection.